# pdf page margins with snappy and symfony2

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to develop a web page that will generate a pdf. I was wondering if there is a way to customize the page margins of the pdf using KnpSnappyBundle for symfony2.  I did a cursory search for this and couldn't find any information. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass options as the second argument of each generating method :

```
$snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
$options = [
    'margin-top'    => 50,
    'margin-right'  => 50,
    'margin-bottom' => 50,
    'margin-left'   => 50,
];

$snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html, $options);
```

Or use `setOption` :

```
foreach ($options as $margin => $value) {
    $snappy->setOption($margin, $value);
}

$snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html, $options);
```

See the whole `knp_snappy.pdf` [class](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/blob/master/src/Knp/Snappy/Pdf.php) and [available wkhtmltopdf options](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/blob/master/src/Knp/Snappy/Pdf.php#L78).

Note that if you are generating PDF from HTML, you should try to use CSS for your margins before use wkhtmltopdf options.