# Snappy footer generate a weird margin proportional to its size

Tags: symfony, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

first, let me show you the piece of code that makes the bug happen.

Here is the code of my footer :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 1rem; background-color: #1C440C">

    <span>Hello world</span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>


    Hello world page

</body>
</html>
```

And the controller :

```
   /**
     * @Route("/path", name="myurl")
     */
    public function toPdf()
    {
        $html = $this->renderView('pdf/page.html.twig');
        $footer = $this->renderView('pdf/footer2_pdf.html.twig');
        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html, array(
                'footer-html' => $footer
            )),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
            )
        );
```

Il I set the footer height to 1 (like it is in the code sample), I get this kind of pdf footer :

[image]

the distance between the "hello world" and the bot of the page looks like the default margin of the pdf, so it looks like it is ok.

Then, if I change the height to 5rem to get a larger footer, I get this :

[image]

The footer is larger, but the margin between the footer and the end of the page just increased like crazy. I don't really understand why.

Thank you for reading, if you know the answer, feel free to answer.

Comment: Did you try this answer to force a fixed margin ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995847/pdf-page-margins-with-snappy-and-symfony2

Comment: I tried to set a margin with @page{margin-bottom: 50} but it was not good. This way with the snappy option did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, just set the bottom margin with this solution :
[pdf page margins with snappy and symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995847/pdf-page-margins-with-snappy-and-symfony2)
Cheers !